# Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathfrak{S}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/ \mathfrak{R} \times \mathbb{R} / \mathfrak{R}$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

> In $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology is considered the following equivalence relation
>   $$x \mathfrak{R} y \; \text{if and only if}\ x,y\in \mathbb{Q}\ (\text{or}\ x=y)$$ $\mathfrak{S}$ $\mathfrak{R}$
>   On the other hand, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology, is defined
>   $$(x,y)\mathfrak{S} (x',y')\; \text{if and only if}\ (x,y),(x',y')\in \mathbb{Q}^2 \; ( \text{or}\ (x,y)=(x',y'))$$
>   Are $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathfrak{S}$ and $\mathbb{R}/ \mathfrak{R} \times \mathbb{R} / \mathfrak{R}$ homeomorphic? More generally, can $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathfrak{S}$ be homeomorphic to a product space?

I've been trying to picture how the quotient spaces look like. All points in $\mathbb{Q}$ are one point in $\mathbb{R}/ \mathfrak{R}$, so if I take $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, then

$$[x]=\{ y\in \mathbb{R} \mid x\mathfrak{R} y\}=\{y\in \mathbb{R} \mid y\in \mathbb{Q} \}=\mathbb{Q}$$
and if $x \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, then
$$[x]=\{x\}$$
and for the other equivalence relation $\mathfrak{S}$ it should work the same way, but I don't know how to prove or disprove whether the two quotient spaces are homeomorphic or not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have the obvious maps $$\phi\colon {\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}^2$$
$$\psi\colon {\mathbb R}^2\to {\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R}$$
$\psi$ induces a well-defined and continuous map of the quotient spaces, while $\phi$ does not: for example $(\pi,0)$ is not mapped to the equivalence class of $(\pi,1)$ for any $\pi\not\in{\mathbb Q}$. So the first space contains a homeomorphic copy of the second. This is just to say that the obvious approach does not work.

Comment: A more serious argument why homeomorphism seems unplausible: if instead of identifying rational numbers one were to identify all irrational numbers, one would have the first space to be uncountable and the second to be countable. So clearly they are not homeomorphic. I'm not sure whether this really makes the claim unplausible in the rational case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $ℝ^2/\mathfrak{S}$ the point rational×rational is dense while all the other points are closed.

In $(ℝ/\mathfrak{R})^2$ the point rational×rational is dense, the points irrational×irrational are closed, and the points rational×irrational and irrational×rational have nowhere-dense closure of size continuum.

Comment: Thanks! There is one thing I don't understand though. What is "nowhere-dense closure of size continuum"?

Comment: Closure of a set $A$ is $\overline{A}$. A subset of a topological space is nowhere-dense if its closure has dense complement. By size I mean cardinality here. Continuum is the cardinality of $ℝ$ or $2^ℕ$.

Comment: Nice! One thing, I've been thinking that the quotient $\mathbb{R}/ \mathfrak{R}$ is $T_0$ but not $T_1$, so the the product of $\mathbb{R}/\mathfrak{R}$ with itself is $T_0$. (I don't know if it's not $T_1$ as well).I've not shown anything yet about $\mathbb{R}^2/ \mathfrak{S}$, but if it is the case that it was $T_1$, Would it suffice to show that no homeomorphism can exist?

Comment: Yes, it would, but neither space is $T_1$ since there are non-closed points as I said.